# Windows Media Player Duration - WinForms

Tags: vb.net, winforms, media-player, windows-media-player, axwindowsmediaplayer

I am trying to get the Duration of the video that i have loaded into my Windows Media Player but it seems to be returning back '0.0'

I need the duration value before the video starts playing as the video length determines the width of a slide.

This is how i am trying to do it at the moment:

```
timeElapsed = AxWindowsMediaPlayer_OnDemand.currentMedia.duration - marker.SyncTime
```

I have also tried this which returns an empty string:

```
Dim asas As String = AxWindowsMediaPlayer_OnDemand.currentMedia.getItemInfo("Duration")
```

Does anyone have any idea of how to get the length of the video loaded in?

Comment: Did you finally find any solution my friend?

Answer (score 2):

Add a reference to Windows Media Player

Use the follow 2 lines in your function to call it

```
Dim VidSecs As Integer = Math.Round(GetMediaDuration(YourFilePath))'Get total seconds
Dim Vidhhmmss As String = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(Math.Round(GetMediaDuration(YourFilePath))).ToString ' Format hh:mm:ss


Public Function GetMediaDuration(ByVal MediaFile As String)
        Try
            Dim w As New WMPLib.WindowsMediaPlayer
            Dim m As WMPLib.IWMPMedia = w.newMedia(MediaFile)
            w.close()
            Return m.duration
        Catch ex As Exception
            Return 0
        End Try
    End Function
```